# Can't login through Django's Admin page

Tags: python, sql, django, authentication, logout

I have already created a custom user model for profiling and Authentication, however it doesn't seem to authenticate the password. I tried numerous times on changing it and even confirmed it on shell but it still doesn't go through on Django Admin.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

# Create your models here.


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, user_type=None, is_superuser=False, is_pqa=False, is_staff=False, is_admin=False, is_test_lead=False, is_test_manager=False, is_active=True):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address!")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have a password!")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.user_type = user_type
        user_obj.ad = is_admin
        user_obj.superuser = is_superuser
        user_obj.tm = is_test_manager
        user_obj.pqa = is_pqa
        user_obj.tl = is_test_lead
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_pqa(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_pqa=True,
            is_staff=True,
            user_type=1
        )
        return user

    def create_staff(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            user_type=2
        )
        return user

    def create_test_lead(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_test_lead=True,
            is_staff=True,
            user_type=3
        )
        return user

    def create_test_manager(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_test_manager=True,
            is_staff=True,
            user_type=4
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            is_admin=True,
            is_superuser=True,
            is_staff=True,
            user_type=5
        )
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'pqa'),
        (2, 'tester'),
        (3, 'test_lead'),
        (4, 'test_manager'),
        (5, 'admin'),
    )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    hire_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    ad = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # superuser/admin
    # non-superuser but with Team Manager Privilages
    tm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # non-superuser but with PQA Privilages
    pqa = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ts = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # non-superuser
    # non-superuser but with TL Privilages
    tl = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.full_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.full_name

    @property
    def is_pqa(self):
        return self.pqa

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.ts

    @property
    def is_test_lead(self):
        return self.tl

    @property
    def is_test_manager(self):
        return self.tm

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.ad

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.superuser
```

And here is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for ceres project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@3xm&$=ky!sq2_i$-9cd%48ork1l$1y-+e__g_4d!+3*2ssli-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'profiles.apps.ProfilesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles.User'  # Custom model

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ceres.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ceres.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I really would appreciate if someone would point me at the right direction for this, since I'm at a loss. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked through your database whether the superuser has been created yet?

Comment: Yes, I have looked through the shell and it is indeed a superuser

Comment: You will find an answer that might help you in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261120/how-to-allow-superusers-to-access-django-admin-panels/69424372#69424372

Answer (score 1):

Create a new superuser by

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

you will be able to login

Comment: I already created a superuser but I get a authentication error.

Comment: You can create as many you want this would be faster instead of dwelling around old superuser

Comment: you are trying with username or email because you have specified     `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Comment: Im a using email to verify

Comment: try username and password once looks like this doesnt seem to work `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverFlow!

**Possible Steps:**

**1)** Check your superuser from command line. Mozilla MDN Docs are an incredible resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site (Go to "Creating a SuperUser" heading)

**2)** Maybe it's a configuration thing?

Check out this [article](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/) by testdriven.io. They do go over creating a custom User Model from the beginning but I think you'll find it helpful even though they're working with email and usernames as they go through all the necessary configurations to get the customizations to show correctly (their "Conclusion" part looks amazing!).

You might find it more helpful to skip to "User Model" since it talks about the AbstractUser right after.

**3)** Again, Django docs are great! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue , my solution is add lines below in my settings.py :

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost' ==> or whatever domain for your website (I am running it locally)
```

Try and see if it works for you