# Can't login to django admin after successfully creating a super user with a custom user model

Tags: django, mongodb, rest, django-custom-user

imm trying to login to the django admin panel with a successfully created superuser but cannot get the right username/pw combo right.

I want users to just use their email as their username. I've deleted migrations, sycndb, and everything works except logging in to the admin panel.

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password= None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('email required')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('username required')

        user = self.model(
            email= self.normalize_email(email),
            username= username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using= self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email= self.normalize_email(email),
            password= password,
            username= username,
        )
        user.is_admin= True
        user.staff= True
        user.is_superuser= True
        user.save(using= self._db)
        return user


class Accounts(AbstractBaseUser):
    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name= 'email', max_length= 60, unique= True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length= 30, unique= True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name= 'date joined', auto_now_add= True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name= 'last login', auto_now= True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default= True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default= False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj= None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
        return True
```

> admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Accounts

admin.site.register(Accounts)
```

> settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'articles',
    'accounts',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Accounts'


ROOT_URLCONF = 'restApi.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I think it must be something to do with the way the password is being saved and returned, because no matter what I do I get the "Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." message.

imm using mongodb database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `user.staff= True` in `MyAccountManager.create_superuser()`, but it should be `user.is_staff = True` (you're missing **`is_`**).

Answer (score 0):

You will find an answer that might help you in here: [How to Allow Superusers to access Django Admin Panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261120/how-to-allow-superusers-to-access-django-admin-panels/69424372#69424372)

If you still cannot log in, run `python manage.py createsuperuser` and create a new superuser and try to log in with that one

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this in your createsuperuser method before saving your data to the database:

> is_admin = True

and

> is_superuser = True

. And that should fix the problem